# Windows 8 UI not loading

Tags: windows-8, user-interface

I experienced a weird issue in Windows 8. When I go to the Home Screen, this is what I see:

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbAU.png)

And the Settings(Not Control Panel) doesn't load and some files might be missing. Do I need to reinstall Windows or does anyone know what the issue is here? Thanks for the answers and have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Windows 8.1 Refresh (Recovery options if I remember correctly). That will keep all your data, refresh all your Windows 8.1 apps, but you will have to reinstall software. I did this once and reinstalling software was not difficult or excessively time consuming.

You might at this point, just upgrade to Windows 10 which is a much better operating system

Comment: Is it possible to refresh from the control panel? Because as I said the Settings don't load up.

Comment: Use the Recovery options if you can get to them. Maybe try starting in Safe Mode

Comment: If Safe Mode does not work and no way to get to Refresh, then upgrading to Windows 10 is your best option